# Увеличение товаров в корзине

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Необходимо реализовать возможность увеличения/уменьшения/изменения товаров в корзине с помощью Ajax (не обновляя страницу)

У меня имеется метод в контроллере:

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IncreaseProductCount(int id)
    {
        cartService.IncrementCount(id);
        return RedirectToAction("Cart");
    }
```

В CartService обрабатывается поиск товара и его увеличение.

В представлении "Cart" имеется такая разметка, для каждого элемента в корзине:

```
<!--Кнопка минус-->
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning item-minus" data-product="@product.Product.Id">
     <span class="fa fa-minus"></span>
</a>
<!--Поле с количеством-->
<input type="text" size="2" value="@product.Count" data-product="@product.Product.Id" class="product-count form-control"/>
<!--Кнопка плюс-->
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger item-plus" id="" data-product="@product.Product.Id">
    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
</a>
```

В @section scripts{} имеется такой сценарий (для кнопки +)

```
   $('.item-plus').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("IncreaseProductCount", "Production")',
            data: { 'id': $(this).attr('data-product') },
            success: function(result) {
                $('body').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Проблема:** при использовании RedirectToRouteResult возвращается разметка переданного представления *полностью*, поэтому я использовал $('**body**').html(result). С этим вроде бы всё работает, но только при каждом клике формируется "борода" классов у `html class=".....">`, которые при каждом клике копируются. С каждым кликом страничка всё больше и больше "тормозит".

Как бы и не логично каждый раз передавать всю страницу целиком, но помимо значений в представлении, мне необходимо обновлять и общее кол-во товаров в шапке.

Подскажите как это сделать :)

Comment: Если используется Ajax метод IncreaseProductCount должен просто возвращать результат операции. Или общее количество товаров в корзине, к примеру.

Comment: Но у меня в методе InreaceProductCount, вызывается метод сервиса CartService "IncrementCount", который увеличивает количество продукта в корзине хранящейся в сессии. Тем самым мне необходимо обновить количество элемента в представлении Cart и  обновить общее количество в шапке странице (а точнее в частичном представлении _ItemsInCart, которое используется в _Layout). Т.е. было бы правильным, ничего не возвращать, а обновить все элементы в корзине и их общее количество